Filtering on related Entities
How can i filter and retrieve only the needed items in a related entity?
Eg. If the PurchaseTrans has items with 3 types of brands and i need only 1 type.. now it returns all the 3 brands if even 1 of them is like the query brand.
var ressales = await _dbcontext.s_purmas
    .Include(c => c.PurchaseTrans)
    .ThenInclude(c => c.Item)
    .Where(r=> r.sdate >= dtfrom && r.sdate <= dtto)
    .Where(r=> r.cancel == "0")
    .Where(p => p.PurchaseTrans.Any(t => EF.Functions.Like(t.Item.brand_name, brand)))
    .OrderBy(r => r.id)
    .ToListAsync();

ive tried changing .Any .All but still not working
Edit:
This also not working :
   .Where(p => p.PurchaseTrans.Any(t => t.Item.brand_name == brand))

The Class
public class PurchaseMaster
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public DateOnly? sdate { get; set; }  

   public DateOnly? pur_date { get; set; }  
   public string refno { get; set; } = string.Empty;
   public string? sup_code { get; set; }
   public string? sup_name { get; set; }

   public string? lcno { get; set; }
   public string? veno { get; set; }
   public string? ordno { get; set; }
   public string? cancel { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<PurchaseTran> PurchaseTrans { get;set; }  = new List<PurchaseTran>();
}

// Dependent (child)
public class PurchaseTran
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string brand { get; set; }
   public string stk_no { get; set; } 
   public string refno { get; set; } 
   public double cost { get; set; }

   public double rec_qty { get; set; }
   public int? vat { get; set; }

   public double? vatrate { get; set; }
   public int purchaseid { get; set; } // Required foreign key property

   public int itemId { get; set; } 
   public virtual PurchaseMaster PurchaseMaster { get; set; } = null; // Required reference navigation to principal

   public virtual Item Item { get; set; }

}


Could  you please share related entity class so that I can be reproduced accordingly and what output you are trying to achieve that would if great if you can explain.

In addition, have tired == instead of function.like? Would you kindly check this .Where(p => p.PurchaseTrans.Any(t => t.Item.brand_name == brand))

Within your code .Any(t => EF.Functions.Like(t.Item.brand_name, brand)) causing the issue. Becuase it checks if at least one PurchaseTran within a PurchaseMaster has a brand matching the query. This will return all PurchaseMasters that have any PurchaseTrans with the matching brand, even if there are others with different. You could use this instead,  Where(r => r.PurchaseTrans.All(t => EF.Functions.Like(t.Item.brand_name, brand)))

if its "All" it returns nothing. if i make it "Any" and if at least 1 record is true it returns all.  I added the entity class also. Thanks

I am not sure hows your data is residing there, But I have tried with sample data and got following output. You could check that.

In addition to filter, which is correct, you have to duplicate this filter for Include. Include loads all child entities if filter not specified .
var ressales = await _dbcontext.s_purmas
    .Include(c => c.PurchaseTrans.Where(t => EF.Functions.Like(t.Item.brand_name, brand)))
    .ThenInclude(c => c.Item)
    .Where(r=> r.sdate >= dtfrom && r.sdate <= dtto)
    .Where(r=> r.cancel == "0")
    .Where(p => p.PurchaseTrans.Any(t => EF.Functions.Like(t.Item.brand_name, brand)))
    .OrderBy(r => r.id)
    .ToListAsync();



How can i filter and retrieve only the needed items in a related
entity?
Eg. If the PurchaseTrans has items with 3 types of brands and i need
only 1 type.. now it returns all the 3 brands if even 1 of them is
like the query brand.

Based on your current code snippet and description I have tried to reproduce your issue and I found that, EF.Functions.Like(t.Item.brand_name, brand)) checks if at least one PurchaseTran within a PurchaseMaster has a brand matching the query. This will return all PurchaseMasters that have any PurchaseTrans with the matching brand, even if there are others with different brands.
Instead of that, I have tried as following:
var purchaseMasters = new List<PurchaseMaster>
{
    new PurchaseMaster
    {
        id = 1,
        sdate = new DateOnly(2024, 4, 1),
        cancel = "0",
        PurchaseTrans = new List<PurchaseTran>
        {
            new PurchaseTran { id = 1, brand = "BrandA", Item = new Item { brand_name = "BrandA" } },
            new PurchaseTran { id = 2, brand = "BrandB", Item = new Item { brand_name = "BrandB" } }
        }
    },
    new PurchaseMaster
    {
        id = 2,
        sdate = new DateOnly(2024, 4, 2),
        cancel = "1",
        PurchaseTrans = new List<PurchaseTran>
        {
            new PurchaseTran { id = 3, brand = "BrandC", Item = new Item { brand_name = "BrandC" } },
            new PurchaseTran { id = 4, brand = "BrandA", Item = new Item { brand_name = "BrandA" } }
        }
    }
};

    string brand = "BrandA"; 
    DateTime dtfrom = new DateTime(2024, 4, 1); 
    DateTime dtto = new DateTime(2024, 4, 30); 

    var ressales = purchaseMasters
        //.Where(pm => pm.sdate >= dtfrom && pm.sdate <= dtto)
        .Where(pm => pm.cancel == "0")
        .Where(pm => pm.PurchaseTrans.Any(pt => pt.brand == brand))
        .OrderBy(pm => pm.id)
        .ToList();

    //Checking Output the results in local console
    foreach (var purchase in ressales)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Purchase ID: {purchase.id}");

        foreach (var purchaseTrans in purchase.PurchaseTrans)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($" - Transaction ID: {purchaseTrans.id}, Brand: {purchaseTrans.brand}");
        }
    }

According to my test, modified query should print out the purchase ID along with the associated supplier name, and for each transaction within that purchase, it will print out the transaction ID and the brand of the associated item which cancel status equal to "0".
Therefore, you could use .Any(pt => pt.brand == brand)) instead of Any(t => EF.Functions.Like
Output:
With cancel = "0", there should be 1 PurchaseMaster along with two transaction and I am getting expected result.



This is LINQ-to-object. That's not useful when the question is about EF. Also, what you say about Like isn't true, or confusing at best. Like doesn't span multiple records, it's still just a predicate that evaluates each record individually. In LINQ-to-objects terms: if you use .Any(pt.brand.Contains(brand)) you still get the same results.

I agree with, I just tried the quick fix.
